# Proof of Goursat's integral lemma when a function has a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, complex-integration

During the course of complex analysis, our professor stated Goursat's integral lemma as follows: "let $f$ be continuous on $D$ and be analytic on $D−z_0$, then the integral of $f$ on the perimeter of a rectangle is $0$".
The proof she gave us is the following:
$$|I|=|\int_{\partial R}f(z)dz|\le\sum_{i=1}^4|\int_{\partial R_i}f(z)dz|\le4|\int_{\partial R_1}f(z)dz|$$
I is the integral we want to show is $0$, $\partial$R is the perimeter of the rectangle: then we divide $R$ into $4$ smaller rectangles $R_i$. In the last step, $R_1$ is the rectangle on which the integral has its maximum value.
Repeating this procedure many times (dividing $R_1$ into more smaller rectangles) we reach this point:
$$|I|\le4^k|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|$$
Now we consider $z_0\in R_k$: we know $f$ is analytic in $z_0$, so:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\space\exists\delta>0: \text{ if } \space|z-z_0|<\delta\space \text{ then }\space |f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0)|<\epsilon|z-z_0|$$
If I split $R$ in enough rectangles (if $k$ is big enough) I can say that $$|z-z_0|<\delta \space\forall z\in R_k$$
I can choose $\delta=L/2^k$ where $L$ is the measure of the perimeter of $R$ and $L/2^k$ is the perimeter of $R_k$. So $|z-z_0|<L/2^k$ and:
$$|f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0)|<\epsilon L/2^k$$
Now I can write:
$$|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|=|\int_{\partial R_k}(f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0))dz|$$
This is because $f(z_0)$ and $f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$ are continuous with their primitive function continuous too, so their integral is $0$ (we already proved this before this theorem).
So:
$$|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|=|\int_{\partial R_k}(f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0))dz|\le \int_{\partial R_k}|f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0)|dz\le \epsilon L/2^k\int_{\partial R_k}dz=\epsilon L^2/4^k$$
In conclusion,
$$|I|=|\int_{\partial R}f(z)dz|\le4^k|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|\le 4^k \epsilon L^2/4^k\le \epsilon L^2$$
Since we can take epsilon as small as we want, then I must be $0$.
This is the proof if there isn't any removable singularity.
In case there is a singularity, if it is in a smaller rectangle which is not the one with the biggest value of the integral, then the proof doesn't change.
If it is exactly in the $R_k$ rectangle we consider in the end, of course we can't say $f$ is analytic there, so, instead of this step:
$$|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|=|\int_{\partial R_k}(f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z0))dz|\le \int_{\partial R_k}|f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0)|dz\le \epsilon L/2^k\int_{\partial R_k}dz=\epsilon L^2/4^k$$
we use the Darboux inequality, saying that:
$$|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|\le \max(|f(z)| \space \text{ on } \space R_k)\cdot\partial R_k$$
Since $\partial R_k$ tends to $0$ when $k$ is big, the integral tends to $0$ too.
After this I asked my professor why then we couldn't use this last simple proof even if there was not a removable singularity, since it seemed much easier than everything done before.
She said it was not possible, because
$$|I|\le4^k|\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz|$$ so we can't just show that $\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz$ tends to $0$: we have to make sure it does "faster" than $4^k$.
Which makes a lot of sense, but, if so, what we showed at the end for the case with a removable singularity is useless, since we only know that $\int_{\partial R_k}f(z)dz$ tends to $0$.
Could you help me understand?

Comment: If the singularity in $z_0$ is removable then $f$ is just analytic on $D$ since $f$ is already defined at $z_0$, and as such you wouldn't need an alternate proof. Removable means that $f$ can be extended into an analytic function on $D$. What you and/or your professor meant should be "singularity" without "removable" most likely? The "malicious" part is that, once you have Goursat's lemma and Morera's theorem, said singularity is indeed removable, but you need to show Goursat's lemma without pre-assuming that the singularity is removable to conclude that.

Comment: (By the way, if you want to make bars, parentheses, etc... match the size of their content, you can use `\left` and `\right`, like this: `\left( thing \right)`)

Comment: @BrunoB thank you for your answer, I had never understood that if the singularity is removable, then the function is analytic on D. I think I got confused by my professor since she added that last part of the proof separately. Thank you also for your suggestion about bars, parenthesis etc. I had barely ever written a post on this website using equations so I found it a bit difficult to write all that stuff; next time I will pay attention to that too.

Comment: Writing in MathJax/LaTeX is hard at the start for almost everyone, no need to worry ;)

Comment: This depends on what definition was used for a "removable singularity". It is common to define a removable singularity at $z_0$ by $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z - z_0) f(z) = 0$. In this case, it takes a bit more development to show that the limit condition means that $f$ can always be extended to $z_0$ to be analytic there. One way of doing so is by Cauchy's integral theorem, which depends in turn on Cauchy's theorem, which then must be proved to still hold when there is a "removable singularity" in the region. However, that limit condition  allows you to conclude the same result as known analycity.